# How to read and use the time for each key press in python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I'm have just started working with Raspberry PI 3. So my first project is an RC car which I am controlling with a keyboard. Unfortunately, I'm facing some problems.

For now, I'm using `time.sleep()` function to limit the time for which each case is performed. Or else the car keeps performing that case until I press Enter. But I was hoping if the pi could read how long I press the keys and perform that function for that specific length of time.

For example, if I press up key for 2 seconds, the car will go forward for 2 seconds. Here is my code:

```
import curses
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
screen.keypad(True)

try:
while True:
    char = screen.getch()
    if char == ord('q'):
        break

    elif char == curses.KEY_UP:
        GPIO.output(7,True)
        GPIO.output(11,False)
        GPIO.output(13,True)
        GPIO.output(15,False)
        time.sleep(.25)
        GPIO.output(7,False)
        GPIO.output(11,False)
        GPIO.output(13,False)
        GPIO.output(15,False)

    elif char == curses.KEY_DOWN:
        GPIO.output(7,False)
        GPIO.output(11,True)
        GPIO.output(13,False)
        GPIO.output(15,True)
        time.sleep(.25)
        GPIO.output(7,False)
        GPIO.output(11,False)
        GPIO.output(13,False)
        GPIO.output(15,False)

    elif char == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
        GPIO.output(7,False)
        GPIO.output(11,True)
        GPIO.output(13,True)
        GPIO.output(15,False)
        time.sleep(.25)
        GPIO.output(7,False)
        GPIO.output(11,False)
        GPIO.output(13,False)
        GPIO.output(15,False)

    elif char == curses.KEY_LEFT:
        GPIO.output(7,True)
        GPIO.output(11,False)
        GPIO.output(13,False)
        GPIO.output(15,True)
        time.sleep(.25)
        GPIO.output(7,False)
        GPIO.output(11,False)
        GPIO.output(13,False)
        GPIO.output(15,False)

    elif char == ord('w'):
        GPIO.output(7,True)
        GPIO.output(11,False)
        GPIO.output(13,True)
        GPIO.output(15,False)
        time.sleep(.1)
        GPIO.output(7,False)
        GPIO.output(11,False)
        GPIO.output(13,False)
        GPIO.output(15,False)

    elif char == ord('d'):
        GPIO.output(7,False)
        GPIO.output(11,True)
        GPIO.output(13,True)
        GPIO.output(15,False)
        time.sleep(.1)
        GPIO.output(7,False)
        GPIO.output(11,False)
        GPIO.output(13,False)
        GPIO.output(15,False)

    elif char == ord('s'):
        GPIO.output(7,False)
        GPIO.output(11,True)
        GPIO.output(13,False)
        GPIO.output(15,True)
        time.sleep(.1)
        GPIO.output(7,False)
        GPIO.output(11,False)
        GPIO.output(13,False)
        GPIO.output(15,False)

    elif char == ord('a'):
        GPIO.output(7,True)
        GPIO.output(11,False)
        GPIO.output(13,False)
        GPIO.output(15,True)
        time.sleep(.1)
        GPIO.output(7,False)
        GPIO.output(11,False)
        GPIO.output(13,False)
        GPIO.output(15,False)



finally:
curses.nocbreak(); screen.keypad(0); curses.echo()
curses.endwin()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

I'm new to python and was hoping someone could help me.

Comment: Let's say that I press the forward key for 2 seconds, just after I finish pressing the respective task, or during the pressing?

Comment: And if no button is pressed that task must perform, or rather in what state should the outputs be?

Comment: All output should be 0. In the case of the same project on Arduino platform, I used to sent a specific character from an app to stop the car when I stopped pressing a button on the same app. I was hoping if I could do the same with raspberry pi rc car.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach, the car will go forward as long you don't press another key:

```
def clearGPIO():
    for pin in [7, 11, 13, 15]:
          GPIO.output(pin, False)

while True:
    char = screen.getch()
    if char == ord('q'):
        clearGPIO()
        break

    elif char == curses.KEY_UP:
         clearGPIO()
         GPIO.output(7, True)

    elif char == curses.KEY_DOWN:
         clearGPIO()
         for pin in [11, 15]:
              GPIO.output(pin, True)
```